# GPU error: Sagemaker mp.p2.xlarge instance using tensorflow==2.3.0

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I got the following error when trying to train my tensorflow model on sagemaker ml.p2.xlarge instance. I use tensorflow==2.3.0. I wonder whether this is because of the tensorflow version incompatibility with cuda. sagemaker ml.p2.xlarge seems to use cuda 10.0

```
GPU error:
2020-08-31 08:46:46.429756: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/openmpi/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
2020-08-31 08:47:02.170819: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/openmpi/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
2020-08-31 08:47:02.764874: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1753] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably old, but it falls back on an open issue found at the beginning of choosing which versions of frameworks to use.
The problem does not depend on the type of instance that you specified (which has NVidia GPU).

From the official documentation "[Available Deep Learning Containers Images](https://aws.amazon.com/it/releasenotes/available-deep-learning-containers-images/)", to date 20/10/2022, **precompiled** versions higher than 2.2 do not seem to be usable:

| Framework | Job Type | Horovod Options | CPU/GPU | Python Version Options | Example URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TensorFlow 2.2 (Cuda 10.2) | training | Yes | GPU | 3.7 (py37) | 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-training:2.2.0-gpu-py37-cu102-ubuntu18.04 |
| TensorFlow 2.2 | inference | No | GPU | 3.7 (py37) | 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-inference:2.2.0-gpu-py37-cu102-ubuntu18.04 |

Within the [dockerfile](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-training-toolkit/blob/tf-2/docker/2.1.0/py3/Dockerfile.gpu) that is used to use the container is the instruction to install the libraries that your **custom version** is missing:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --allow-unauthenticated \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    ca-certificates \
    cuda-command-line-tools-10-1 \
    cuda-cudart-dev-10-1 \
    cuda-cufft-dev-10-1 \
    cuda-curand-dev-10-1 \
    cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1 \
    cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1 \
    curl \
    libcudnn7=7.6.2.24-1+cuda10.1 \
    # TensorFlow doesn't require libnccl anymore but Open MPI still depends on it
    libnccl2=2.4.7-1+cuda10.1 \
    libgomp1 \
    libnccl-dev=2.4.7-1+cuda10.1 \
    ....
```

Then you can **install the required libraries** from your custom version directly with a requirements.txt file or run the install command directly in the training script.

If there are no special project requirements, I recommend using the precompiled versions of sagemaker. Otherwise, build a docker image from scratch instead of installing libraries this way..